# Fetch in React making call continuosly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch, fetch-api

I am fetching the data from json file but the issue is that when i checked network tab. It's being call continuosly what can i do to resolve the problem.
: [Network Tab Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnlHT.png)

```
class Banner extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          buttonLink:"",
          bannerImg:""
        };
    }


    render() {


        const a =  fetch("./logo.json").then(response => response.json())
        .then((temp1)=> {this.setState({buttonLink:temp1.buttonLink,bannerImg:temp1.bannerImg});  
    });
   
return(....
<img src={this.state.bannerImg}></img>
....
)
```

Comment: You make the `fetch` call in `render` which alters state when it completes, thus triggering another render. See the problem? I think you're meant to use `componentDidMount` to perform these sorts of side-effects

Comment: take the fetch out of the render method because any change to the props or or state will rerender it causing unnenessary reloads. Instead put it into a componentDidMount method.

Comment: It is because in every setState it will recall the render function.
so every API fetch success it will call setState and it will again call render function. that's why it is going to an infinite loop. learn react basics first and then start developing. check lifecycle methods in react

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in class component you can use some lifecycle methods like componentDidMount
so put your fetch method inside of a componentDidMount not in render method because whenever you call setState() method, it will call render method again,and inside of your render method you call api and setState again,  that makes an inifinite loop, do something like this:

```
 componentDidMount(){
   const a = fetch("./logo.json").then(response => response.json())
  .then((temp1)=> {this.setState({buttonLink:temp1.buttonLink,bannerImg:temp1.bannerImg});  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call fetch inside `render` function.

You can use functional component to easily fetch the data.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Banner = () => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState({ buttonLink: '', bannerImg: '' });

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('./logo.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((temp1) => {
                setImage({ buttonLink: temp1.buttonLink, bannerImg: temp1.bannerImg });
            });
    }, []);

    return <img src={image.bannerImg}></img>;
};

export default Banner;
```